# Fonts missing in oh-my-zsh on WSL

Tags: fonts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zsh

Im trying to setup Oh-my-zsh on WSL Ubuntu 18.04 with agnoster theme

I already follow this guide : https://blog.joaograssi.com/windows-subsystem-for-linux-with-oh-my-zsh-conemu/

I've installed all the powerline fonts possible, but there are still missing characters :

```
echo "\ue0b0 \u00b1 \ue0a0 \u27a6 \u2718 \u26a1 \u2699"
 ±     
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the font for the Terminal:

1. Start the Windows Subsystem for Linux
2. Right-click on the window and select the properties
3. Select one of the fonts with Powerline in its name
4. Confirm with "OK"

[image]

Comment: I am not seeing any poweline fonts in the list. Also I am using wsl in Windows trminal

Answer (score 4):

Install the [DejaVuSansMono](https://github.com/powerline/fonts/tree/master/DejaVuSansMono) font from the [Powerline fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) repo. I'm using the agnoster theme which works well it. You should be ok to install just DejaVuSansMono, alternatively you can use the script in the repository to install all the themes.

Now you can right click the title window of your Ubuntu terminal, Go to Properties and set the DejaVuSansMono for Powerline font and it should fix it.

[Here is a good blog on this also.](https://blog.nillsf.com/index.php/2020/02/17/setting-up-wsl2-windows-terminal-and-oh-my-zsh/)

Answer (score 0):

After installing Powerline fonts, all you have to do is to open the Setting --> Distro -->Appearence --> Under Text (Select Font-Face)
[image]